# Angular 5: show status text based on output

Tags: angular, angular5

In Angular 5, I want to show different text based on the output which I received from PHP back end (array). Say, for each record there is a status field. The status can be either "submitted", "cancelled", 'requestforcost" and etc. I wanted to show the status into the view (in Angular 5) file as if the status is 'requestforcost', it will print as "Request For Cost. If the status is 'cancelled', it will print as "Cancelled" and etc. Should I use "NgIf, Else, Then"?
Currently I've written the code as below:

```
<td class="font-size-md">{{item.status}}</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using your current approach you can do either this:

```
<td class="font-size-md">{{ getText(item.status) }}</td>
```

In your .ts file

```
getText(status) {
   if (status === "submitted") return "Submitted"
   if (status === "cancelled") return "Cancelled"
   if (status === "requestforcost") return "Request For Cost"
}
```

Or you can do this in your template:

```
<td
   *ngIf="item.status === 'submitted'"
   class="font-size-md">
   submitted
</td>

<td
   *ngIf="item.status === 'cancelled'"
   class="font-size-md">
   Cancelled
</td>

<td
   *ngIf="item.status === 'requestforcost'"
   class="font-size-md">
   Request For Cost
</td>
```

Or you can also do this:

```
<td class="font-size-md">
   <span *ngIf="item.status === 'submitted'">Submitted</span>
   <span *ngIf="item.status === 'cancelled'">Cancelled</span>
   <span *ngIf="item.status === 'requestforcost'">Request For Cost</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Yes, just showing it in case if the person don't know this could be an option too.

Answer (score 7):

You can have multiple conditional; `tds` like:

```
<td class="font-size-md" *ngIf="item?.status == 'requestforcost'">Request For Cost</td>
<td class="font-size-md" *ngIf="item?.status == 'cancelled'">Cancelled</td>
```

.. etc

or create a different container variable in your `ts` which maps the statuses to the text you want to display, like:

```
let statusMap = {requestforcost: "Request For Cost", cancelled: "Cancelled"}
```

and in your `HTML`
have the `td` like:

```
<td class="font-size-md" *ngIf="item?.status>{{statusMap[item.status]}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this like below.

```
<td class="font-size-md" *ngIf="item.status === 'submitted">Show here submitted text</td>
<td class="font-size-md" *ngIf="item.status === 'cancelled">Show here submitted text</td>
```